# Uniform EditText size

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm trying to get all edit text views to be the same size without using a hard definition like px or dp, but rather to use a wrap_content and get them all to be the same size. This is what I have, but it doesn't work:

```
    enterAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAge);
    enterAge.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher1());

    enterWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterWeight);
    enterWeight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher2());
    enterWeight.setWidth(enterAge.getWidth());

    enterHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterHeight);
    enterHeight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher3());
    enterHeight.setWidth(enterAge.getWidth());

    enterMealFrequency = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterMealFrequency);
    enterMealFrequency.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher4());
    enterMealFrequency.setWidth(enterAge.getWidth());
```

Any suggestions on why this isn't working the way I want it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved similar problem introducing my own class which extends EditText, e.g.

```
public class SimpleEditText extends EditText
{
    private static float textSize=14.0;

    public SimpleEditText(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        this.setTextSize(textSize);
    }

    public SimpleEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setTextSize(textSize);
    }

    public SimpleEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.setTextSize(textSize);
    }
}
```

In resource you can directly use reference to SimpleEditText instead of EditText (for sure one have to keep in mind that all size related XML attributes will be ignored...)

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on when you are executing this code.  The values for the width and height of a `View` will not return valid data in Java code until layout is complete (this happens sometime later than when the layout is inflated from XML).  If you are doing this in `onCreate()` or even `onResume()`, this is too early and `getWidth()` will likely return zero.

You need to work with the layout system to determine when you will have valid view sizes to work with.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: That is the wrong thing to do; there is nothing that specifies a focus change will happen after the first layout or any other layout that may be important.  You need to do what the documentation says -- interact with the layout system, by writing a parent view that can implement things like onLayout() to decide how to layout its children.  Also APIs like setWidth() are *only* for use by layout managers to position their children.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Dianne; didn't realize that.  I removed the offending suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

wrap_content is fundamentally the opposite of what you are saying -- it specifies to make the view only as large as it needs to be, regardless of the parent size.

You need to write your UI as a view hierarchy with layouts describing how to position the views.  It is very simple to create a vertical row of text views that are all given them same width by putting them in a LinearLayout.

Comment: this is true- but what i was aiming for was creating my xml in a way that would fit all screen sizes and dimensions, from tablet to a 2.7 QVGA... so they needed to have size parameters that adjust to the parent size, which depends on the screen.  i ended up just doing it with the layout_weight... except the layout_weight function is expensive, and i had to run it ALL over my layout with multiple children in it.

Comment: If you have very specific special layouts you want to do, you should consider just writing a custom ViewGroup subclass that implements the layout algorithm you want.